# How to read cell data from an Excel document with objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, excel

I'm building an iPhone app that has to download an Excel (.xls) file from a website and perform a string search of the spreadsheet data.  I've done this in C#, but I have no idea how to do this in objective-c.  How do I access the individual cells using objective-c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no innate ability to read Excel data into a Foundation container, like an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. You could, however, convert the file (with Excel) to a comma-separated-value (CSV) file and then parse each line's cells on the iPhone using the `NSString` instance method `-componentsSeparatedByString:`.

Comment: Is it possible in the case of multiple sheets are present in the same document ? , if yes then how ?

Comment: I don't know how Excel formats a multisheet document when exported to CSV. But you could test this pretty easily, though.