# Is there any way to parse Microsoft excel in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to parse an excel sheet and have to display the content in table view. Suggestions please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read cell data from an Excel document with objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313836/how-to-read-cell-data-from-an-excel-document-with-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to save your excel file as a text file with tab delimiters. This way its straight forward. In case you like to do some "intelligent" parsing - you may just take a look at one of these many parser tutorials for the iPhone. I am sure, you will be able to build on these sample quite easily.