# iOS: Read in XLS

Tags: ios, io, xls

I'm trying to figure out how to read in the contents of an XLS document and I'm able to get the bytes just fine, but I don't have any clue where to go from here. Trying `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data.bytes length:data.length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:data.bytes]` both don't get me anywhere (null). What are you supposed to do to read in the contents of an XLS file?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516129/read-data-from-excel-file-in-objective-c-iphone

Comment: @Adam So, basically, there isn't a good way unless if I am looking to spend a lot of time doing it. And even then, I'm not guaranteed to have a steady result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to combine two answer.

"There is no innate ability to read Excel data into a Foundation container, like an NSArray or NSDictionary. You could, however, convert the file (with Excel) to a comma-separated-value (CSV) file and then parse each line's cells on the iPhone using the NSString instance method -componentsSeparatedByString:."

"A comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in plain-text form. Plain text means that the file is a sequence of characters, with no data that has to be interpreted instead, as binary numbers. A CSV file consists of any number of records, separated by line breaks of some kind; each record consists of fields, separated by some other character or string, most commonly a literal TAB or comma. Usually, all records have an identical sequence of fields"

--

[How to read cell data from an Excel document with objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313836/how-to-read-cell-data-from-an-excel-document-with-objective-c)

[objective-c loading data from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974501/objective-c-loading-data-from-excel)

Comment: Oh. Sorry! I completely forgot about your answer. Thanks for the links. Its too bad that there isn't a way to read an XLS directly, but this works for me for now.

Answer (score 1):

Even though saving your Excel file to CSV is the easier answer, sometimes that's not really what you're looking for, so I created [QZXLSReader.](https://github.com/QuetzalMX/QuetzalXLSReader) It's a drag-and-drop solution so it's a lot easier to use. I don't think it's as feature complete, but it worked for me.

It's basically a library that can open XLS files and parse them into Obj-C classes. Once you have the classes, it's very easy to send them to Core Data or a dictionary or what have you.

I hope it helps!

Comment: any sample source or tutorial for reference?