# Parsing Excel files use Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml, excel

Are there any good ways of parsing Excel files in iOS? I had Searched for a lot of informations,and finding Excel2Xml using java.but how I can Parse Excel files use objcetive－C,I have not good ideas.Can you help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313836/how-to-read-cell-data-from-an-excel-document-with-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/purchase.html) have a commercial license and iOS support for $199 (currently). It can be downloaded [here](http://www.libxl.com/download.html).